# I have a MenuItem instance and I get one particular item and set its visibility to false....results in an runtime error

Tags: android, android-menu

null object reference
`android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(true);`

In `onCreateOptionsMenu()` my code is:

```
@Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) { 
mMenu = menu;
inflater.inflate(R.menu.contact_list_menu, menu); 
}
```

In my function `hideMenu()` my code is:

```
mMenuItem.setVisible(false);
```

`contact_list_menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_reimport"
    android:title="@string/reimport"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_reimport_contacts"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Add your menu xml code and `onCreateOptionsMenu` code.

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
        mMenu = menu;
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contact_list_menu, menu);
    }

Comment: Is mMenuItem your global variable?

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_reimport"
        android:title="@string/reimport"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_reimport_contacts"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>

Comment: yes ! private MenuItem mMenuItem; declared globally

Comment: @GaneshRam Is it the complete code in `onCreateOptionsMenu`? Where are you initializing `mMenuItem`?

Comment: Should I need to initialize it? if yes how?